# How to increase the size of main player in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity and C# and I am trying to build a game like roll a ball but what I am trying to achieve is that every time ball hits a cube, 10 points are increased and the size of the ball increases. I was able to display the score but have no idea how can increase the size of the ball and also the distance of the camera from the ball.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class increasingPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 temp;


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.transform.name == "MyPlayer")
        {
            score.Score += 10;
            Debug.Log("Ball Collided");
            Destroy(gameObject);
           
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have till now which is helping me increase the score when the ball collides.
How do I increase the size of my ball and distance of the camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase the size of the ball:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class increasingPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 temp;


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.transform.name == "MyPlayer")
        {
            score.Score += 10;
            Debug.Log("Ball Collided");
            collision.transform.localScale *= 1.1f;
            Destroy(gameObject);
           
        }
    }
}
```

I can't modify your camera location without knowing how its set up.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the problem is that after the ball reaches a certain size, it starts going inside the plain, i.e. the surface on which it is rolling. Also, kindly let me know what do you mean by "camera setup" so that I can elaborate better.

Comment: Well I can't just give you code you can stick in to move your camera without knowing how your camera works; if I say for example, to move the camera's z position back by 1 unit, that might actually move it forwards or sideways.

Comment: To fix the ball going inside the plane, either move its position upwards at the same time as you scale it, or (if its physics based), make sure you are increasing the scale of the collider as well as the MeshRenderer.